# Enaml: How to style a CheckBox

Tags: python, enaml

I'm trying to get the check in a CheckBox to be more visible when the window is not selected.   See the difference in the pics below.

I've had no luck in trying to style it with:

```
    Style:
        element = 'CheckBox'
        Setter:
            field = 'background'
            value = 'yellow '

    Style:
        element = 'CheckBox'
        Setter:
            field = 'color'
            value = 'red'
```

As you can see, this does not style the actual checkbox, only the text field.

So, any ideas on how to style the actual checkbox?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enaml doesn't have control over how the checkbox is rendered. If you *really* need that level of customization, you'll need to write your own custom Qt widget which paints its own checkbox, and then wrap that widget as an Enaml widget.

Comment: Well that's too bad, because the checkmark is barely visible.  I was able to change the overall style using QStyleFactory to 'Plastique' and the checkmark is clearly visible when window is selected or not.   I'd rather use the native mac look but not seeing the checkmarks all the time is unacceptable.